# Does this package contain the SSMS only or the SQL Server 2008 also?

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, sql-server-2008, ssms

I have downloaded SQL Server 2008 Management Studio from https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=7593

I am confused if this package contains just the SSMS or the SQL Server 2008 also?

I already have SQL Server 2005 installed on my machine. So I just want the SSMS 2008.

But after installing the downloaded file from https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=7593, I also find an item SQL Server 2008 in Windows Control Panel.

I am confused what is going on.

So can anyone please help me by exploring the content of the package on the [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=7593), if this contain the Management Studio only, or SQL Server 2008 also?

Comment: It contains a full install of Express. SSMS is *not* available separately until SQL Server 2016. You need https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms

Comment: Hope this question is more suitable to https://dba.stackexchange.com/ but I think a developer itself can answer this question.

Comment: If you're downloading express, why 2008? That version is out of support, and very close to the end of extended support. You'd be much better off choosing a more recent version  (2016 or 2017).

Comment: @gbn .. thnx for ur perfect answer.

Comment: @SathiyaKumar sorry i know

Comment: @larnu I am just learning .. So want to start with a simple lower level version

Comment: But it's not simpler. In fact, there are features in 2008 that don't exist anymore because they were deprecated. If you're going to start learning something new, I'd start with the most recent; otherwise you'll be learning old habits and not learning the new.